# Search string and insert new line javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a long string that appears like

```
var myString = "Bob is the best person in the world MAN John is the best person in the world MAN Peter likes to pick apples daily MAN Fred loves to eat bananas MAN"
```

What I want to try to do is insert a new line after each `MAN` - so that I essentially get

```
Bob is the best person in the world MAN 
John is the best person in the world MAN 
Peter likes to pick apples daily MAN
Fred loves to eat bananas MAN
```

How would I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myString = myString.replace(/MAN/g, "MAN\n");

/*
 returns
 "Bob is the best person in the world MAN\  (\ means new line)
 John is the best person in the world MAN\
 Peter likes to pick apples daily MAN\
 Fred loves to eat bananas MAN"
*/
```

Comment: @Andy - You can replace `/,/` or `/MAN/` with anything you want.

Comment: awesome thanks heaps for that! totally #fail in the brain haha but i'll accept your answer when the timer allows me!

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript replace method:

```
var n=myString.replace(/MAN/g,"MAN\n");
```

If you want to output the string as html, use

```
"<br>" instead of "\n".
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = myString.replace(/MAN/g, "MAN\n");
```

For HTML output, use this instead:

```
myString = myString.replace(/MAN/g, "MAN<br>");
```